# org export interanl [[links]] to keep link text

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-link

When exporting a document such as:

```
 * Title

 Link to [[Title]]
```

The link text is converted to the section number. I.e.

> ## 1. Title
>
> Link to **1**

Is there a way to keep the link text e.g.:

> ## 1. Title
>
> Link to **Title**

Without having to write each link as `[[Title][Title]]`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an easy way to do this other than by copying the `org-html-link` function from ox-html.el. :-(

Find the text `What description to use?`. That's where you want to change the logic:

```
     ;; What description to use?
     (desc
      ;; Case 1: Headline is numbered and LINK has no
      ;; description.  Display section number.
      (if (and (org-export-numbered-headline-p destination info)
           (not desc))
          (mapconcat #'number-to-string
             (org-export-get-headline-number
              destination info) ".")
        ;; Case 2: Either the headline is un-numbered or
        ;; LINK has a custom description.  Display LINK's
        ;; description or headline's title.
        (or desc
        (org-export-data
         (org-element-property :title destination) info)))))
```

This is hacky but you can change this to:

```
     ;; What description to use?
     (desc
      ;; Case 1: Headline is numbered and LINK has no
      ;; description.  Display section number.
      (if (and nil  ; ← **note the change here**
           (org-export-numbered-headline-p destination info)
           (not desc))
          (mapconcat #'number-to-string
             (org-export-get-headline-number
              destination info) ".")
        ;; Case 2: Either the headline is un-numbered or
        ;; LINK has a custom description.  Display LINK's
        ;; description or headline's title.
        (or desc
        (org-export-data
         (org-element-property :title destination) info)))))
```

and then it will never use case 1 (section number) and always use case 2 (link text).

Comment: How about `org-export-filter-link-functions`?